# Time complexity of this "incremental sort"

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

[image: "Incremental sort"]

This uses the same merge function as merge sort, but the input is split differently, so the lists are merged in that way ^

In the worst case scenario, what is the number of comparisons for this algorithm?
I know merge sort is (n log n - n + 1), I assume this sort is slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint: have you seen this algorithm someplace else?  It works by starting with a list of n sorted elements, then adding in an nth element to the end and swapping it down to its proper place.

Once you've figured out what that algorithm is, you should be able to get the best, worst, and average-case runtimes really easily.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't figure it out

Comment: @Foxic- Think about insertion sort.

Answer (score 2):

This sort is O(n^2). For each item added, you compare every item in the existing list.

So here you'll make 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = (n^2 + n)/2 comparisons.

That's assuming you're using a standard merge.

You can do this in-place, too, in which case it's just inserting things into a sorted list. That, too, is O(n^2). You'll make log(n) comparisons to find the position where the item is to be inserted, but then you have to move items down to make space. So inserting each item is n + log(n), making the sort O(n^2 + n log n).

Comment: Doesn't it compare it to the (n/2)th element (or n/2 - 1 if list is even) and halves the list every time? Comparing it to every item in the list would be really inefficient

Comment: @Foxic: You said that it uses the same merge function as merge sort. If so, and you are adding things in ascending order (the worst case), then each new item added will be compared against every item in the existing list.